# I can't see RenderMode-property in ToolStripSeparator c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with `RenderMode`-property of the `ToolStripSeparator`.

When I put the following line of code :

```
this.toolStripSeparator1.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.System;
```

I have the following error :

> error 44  'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' does not contain a
>   definition for 'RenderMode' and no extension method 'RenderMode'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Despite, I put the references

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Below is a list of my references

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Do you have any ideas what could cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToolStripRenderMode Enumeration's value can be assigned to RenderMode property of ToolStrip.
ToolStripSeparator donot have any such property.

I think you should use it like this:

```
toolStrip1.RenderMode=ToolStripRenderMode.System;
```

Comment: thanks, just a question how I can change ToolStripSeparator color   using toolStrip1.RenderMode=ToolStripRenderMode.System;      i put this code but it doesn't work ToolStrip tool = new ToolStrip();
            tool.RenderMode = ToolStripRenderMode.System;
            tool.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripSeparator [] {toolStripSeparator1});